# error "vue-cli-service: command not found" when running a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2

If I execute the following commands from the root of my Vue app (v. 2.6.12)

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm run serve
```

I get the following error

> sh: vue-cli-service: command not found

If I manually add the following symlink to `node_modules/.bin` the error does not occur

```
vue-cli-service -> ../@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
```

But I shouldn't have to do this manually, i.e. if this symlink is required, it should be created when the `@vue/cli-service` package is installed.

I'm using NPM version 7.0.3 and have the following declared in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json`

```
"@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.6"
```

Comment: Will you look at github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2404

Comment: Sometimes caching is the problem.can you try npm run cache clean --force and delete package-lock.json and try to install again.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in another repo and post the link or post the link to the repo with the error? This is most likely a problem with installing the packages, or a cache issue with npm. As an alternative, try using yarn and see if that works better.

Comment: please share your package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing NPM with Yarn 1.X resolved this issue

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to skirt the issue by using the following in your package.json:

```
"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service serve"
```

OR

```
"serve": "node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve"
```

This is just a temporary fix, though, as it is most likely an issue with npm not setting the correct path or npm not installing the binary properly. Try upgrading npm and nvm. See @bravemaster's comment on the github issue, as this contains several potential fixes.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` worked for me in the past, but check the package.json, which should roughly like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue cli must be installed with global flag.

```
npm install -g vue-cli-service
```

If error try same command with `sudo`.

Vue-cli should not be in your `package.json` as a dependency (not even in dev-dependencies) because it is used only to generate a new project from scratch, not being necessary to run/server/build a project. (in dev or  production), as the scripts are set in scripts section from `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with many of my projects using vue-cli-service.
I migrated to vite.
My projects worked.